# Dataloader CLI Error

Tags: data-loader

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOExc
eption parsing XML document from file [C:\Users\12345\Desktop\CLI\process-conf.
xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\552362\Desktop
\CLI\process-conf.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

I have been creating the password and xml over and over again , but getting some error or the other .
Is there anything specific?

I have created the process-config file , log file , config.properties.

Comment: Can you type in the commands that you used to create the password?

Comment: Might be too little too late, but I see a space between after "Desktop" before the backslash that might be making the directory path invalid